# Unwanted extrusions Inside geo node structure

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, extrude

[image]
[image]

I'm fairly new to all of this and have had most of my fun in geometry nodes. I would like to know what I can do to get rid of all this internal mesh-stuff happening inside the object as well as the plots of exposed *waffle* holes scattered about the ground.

Also if I could do this city-gen better LMK how.

Comment: Could you uncheck the *Individual* box in the *Extrude Mesh* node ? According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/operations/extrude_mesh.html#extrude-mesh-node): "A quad side face will be generated on each side of every selected face".

Comment: Hard to know exactly the result you want. Is that just unchecking "individual" extrusion option?